# Calculate moving average using SQL window functions with leading null's where not enough data is avaliable

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want to calculate a moving average using SQL window functions. The following example of a 2 "day" moving average basically works fine, but It also calculates an average if only one data point is available. I rather want the average to be null as long as not enough data is available

```
create table average(
    nr int,
    value float
);

insert into average values (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (4, 10);

SELECT
    nr, 
    value, 
    AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY nr ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING)::FLOAT AS "Moving-Average-2"
FROM average;
```

result:

```
1   2   2
2   4   3
3   6   5
3   8   7
4   10  9
```

expected result:

```
1   2   null
2   4   3
3   6   5
3   8   7
4   10  9
```

EDIT 1: 
Of course the average can be anything not only 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use another window function (`COUNT()`) to make sure that at least two records are available in the window before doing the computation, like:

```
SELECT
    nr, 
    value, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY nr ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) > 1
        THEN AVG(value) OVER (ORDER BY nr ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING)::FLOAT 
        ELSE NULL
    END AS "Moving-Average-2"
FROM average;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o3i9yJn1ABMhorT1dnVEYb/0)**:

```
| nr  | value | Moving-Average-2 |
| --- | ----- | ---------------- |
| 1   | 2     |                  |
| 2   | 4     | 3                |
| 3   | 6     | 5                |
| 3   | 8     | 7                |
| 4   | 10    | 9                |
```

Comment: This is actually the only way which not only can handle different moving average windows but also deal with regular nulls by using a `sum(case when x not null then 1 else 0) > 1`

Answer (score 3):

Since you happen to form the average only between 1 preceding row and the current one, just using [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE)  might be simplest:

```
select nr, value
     ,(value + lag(value, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY nr)) / 2 AS "Moving-Average-2"
from average;
```

`lag()` has an overloaded variant that allows to provide a default value (as 3rd parameter) in case there is no row. Provide `NULL` and you are there. Or, since `NULL` is the default default anyway, just:

```
 ... ,(value + lag(value) OVER (ORDER BY nr)) / 2 AS "Moving-Average-2"
```

While the underlying table column is of type `float`, you need no cast to `float` in this case.

This is assuming the column value is defined `NOT NULL` (like indicated by your sample data). Else you also get `NULL` where the previous row has `value IS NULL` and the current row has a value, while `avg()` returns the value in this case! (Or this may be what you want anyway, given your question.)

Answer (score 2):

This may be a handy place to use a window specification:

```
select a.*,
       (case when row_number() over w > 1
             then avg(value) over w
        end) as running_average
from average a
window w as (order by nr rows between 1 preceding and current row);
```

Comment: This answer was brilliant and super easy to understand, thank very much!!!! I was able to adapt this easily to create a 4 week moving average.

Answer (score 1):

i think null is not come in agv first row otherwise below will work by using

```
BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

select nr, value, 
       avg(value) OVER (ORDER BY nr ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS "Moving-Average-2"
from average;
```

BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

but you can haddle it by useing case when

```
select nr, value, 
       case when nr=1 then null else
       avg(value) OVER (ORDER BY nr ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) end AS "Moving-Average-2"
from average;

nr  value   Moving-Average-2
1   2   
2   4   3
3   6   5
3   8   7
4   10  9
```

[online demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0ad1364d47dac48fa7547a8d65b0e239)